# Eigenvalue of non-symmetric real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a non-symmetric matrix.

Prove that $\lambda_1$ is real, provided that $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|≥|\lambda_3|≥...≥|\lambda_n|$ where $\lambda_i$, $i= 1,...,n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, while others can be real or not real.

Please give me some hints

Comment: Should it be to prove that $\lambda_1$ is real? not $|\lambda_1|$

Comment: What do you know about the roots of a real polynomial?

Comment: Do I need to use characteristic polynomial to prove this?

Comment: @Fabian What is special about the roots of real polynomial, is that the largest root must be real?

Comment: The largest root of a real polynomial need not be real. take $x^2+1$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Presumably you mean "Prove that $\ \lambda_1\ $ is real", since $\ \left\vert z\right\vert\ $ is *always* real for *any* complex or real $\ z\ $.

The fact that the inequality $\ \lambda_1 > \left\vert \lambda_2\right\vert\ $ is a *strict* inequality is significant.  Keeping [Fabian's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7266/fabian) question in mind, would that inequality be possible if $\ \lambda_1\ $ were complex?

Comment: Is that x must be real, but why?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A real matrix has a real characteristic polynomial. Non-real roots of a real polynomial appear always in complex conjugated pairs. Complex conjugated numbers have equal absolute values. What does it say about a root, which absolute value has no pair?